# How to change Vue app meta data in the head section

Tags: vue.js

I need to change the meta data of a Vue APP `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` from "no" to "yes". However I can not get the change to take without manually doing it in the vue-cli-pwa-plugin node module. Have tried the following

- Add property "apple-mobile-web-app-capable": "yes" to manifest.json file
- Add property to pwa.appleMobileWebAppCapable to "yes" in vue.config.js
- Manually setting it to the index.html in the root folder and the one in the public folder

Answer (score -1):

There is a module for Vue that makes changing meta a lot more pleasant - and it's fittingly called `vue-meta`.

Here's the GitHub: https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta